# Group in ranges values extracted from an 'alphanumeric + symbols' string [PostgreSQL]

Tags: string, postgresql, group-by, range, extract

- **Nb.** I am using PostgreSQL.
- **Nb1.** For simplicity purposes I am only showing the two relevant columns for this post, original table has more rows & columns.

I have a table called 'contents' like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<table border="1" style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <td>id</td>
    <td>data</td>  
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4009</td>
    <td>"duration"=>"101", "preview_version"=>"", "twitter_profile"=>"", "creator_category"=>"association", "facebook_profile"=>"", "linkedin_profile"=>"", "personal_website"=>"", "content_expertise_type"=>"image", "content_expertise_categories"=>"1,2,3"</td>  
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4865</td>
    <td>"duration"=>"108", "preview_version"=>"", "twitter_profile"=>"", "creator_category"=>"association", "facebook_profile"=>"", "linkedin_profile"=>"", "personal_website"=>"", "content_expertise_type"=>"image", "content_expertise_categories"=>"4,6"</td>  
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

from this table I need to extract the duration value by using this query:

```
select id,data->'duration' as data from contents
```

which gives me the below result (again, the original table will return many more entries and some values in "data" column will coincide reason why I need to group them in ranges):

```
+------+------+
|  id  | data |
+------+------+
| 4009 |  101 |
| 4865 |  108 |
+------+------+
```

Now that I have the 'data' values I want to tag them in different ranges

```
SELECT d.id,
    case when d.data >= 0 and d.data< 10 then '0-9' 
    when d.data >= 10 and d.data< 20 then '10-19' 
    else '20-500' end as range 
FROM (SELECT id,data->'duration' as data FROM contents) as d
```

But here the query returns this error:

> ERROR:  operator does not exist: text >= integer
>   LINE 3:          case when d.data >= 0 and d.data< 10 then '0-9'
>                                     ^
>   HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.

After this I was hoping to group the ranges like this:

```
SELECT t.range as score_range, count(*) as number_of_ocurrences 
FROM
    (***ABOVE QUERY THAT CURRENTLY RETURNS AN ERROR TO BE PLACED IN HERE***) as t
GROUP BY t.range
ORDER BY score_range
```

Any help to achieve this grouping task will be very much appreciated!

Looking forward to getting an answer! :-)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work if you cast the value:

```
SELECT d.id,
       (case when d.data >= 0 and d.data< 10 then '0-9' 
             when d.data >= 10 and d.data< 20 then '10-19' 
             else '20-500'
        end) as range 
FROM (SELECT id, (data->'duration')::int as data FROM contents
     ) d
```

Answer (score 1):

Json values in Postgres are always strings, it is necessary to cast. For fetching integer values from json fields there is a special operator `->>`

Try to fetch duration as Integer value like

```
select id, data->>'duration' as data from contents
```

More info http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-json.html

Comment: hey @sema, thanks for looking into it. If I use that I get this error: ERROR:  operator does not exist: hstore ->> unknown
LINE 7: FROM (select id, data->>'duration' as data from contents
                             ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.

Comment: Ah, I supposed that you use `json` type instead of `hstore` :) My answer was about json, hstore case answered below :)

Comment: Ok, no problem! happy to review all proposed solutions! thanks all!